# I'm a new programmer and every time I run this block of code I get a null pointer exception in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
//This Is the Class
private String words;
private File textFile;
private Scanner inputFile;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
public Scramble(String j) throws FileNotFoundException
{
File textFile = new File(j);

Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(textFile);
}

public String getRealWord() throws IOException                                    
{
//Make the loop while !null
//if null close the document
while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {

    stringBuilder.append(inputFile);

    }
    inputFile.close();



return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

This is the call to the class in the main method
    String word = theScramble.getRealWord();
What portion should I change to avoid the null pointer exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're re-declaring your variables in the local scope.  Within your `Scramble` constructor:

```
File textFile = new File(j);
```

...is declaring a *new* variable called `textFile`, which hides the instance member also called `textFile`.

You'll want to change:

```
public Scramble(String j) throws FileNotFoundException
{
   File textFile = new File(j);
   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(textFile);
}
```

To:

```
public Scramble(String j) throws FileNotFoundException
{
   textFile = new File(j);
   inputFile = new Scanner(textFile);
}
```

This way, you're referring to the instance variables, not the local variables.